Is it possible to choose $\mathrm{df}$ to make an antiderivative an elementary function?
One other day, I was solving a definite integral of the form $\int \sinh^{-1}(x^2) \mathrm dx$ (with some limits of integration), but in the original problem, the author forgot to write $\mathrm dx$. As far as my knowledge goes, $\mathrm dx$ is important because there's a big difference between $\int e^{-x^2}\mathrm dx$ and $\int e^{-x^2}\mathrm d(x^2)$ as the latter one is just the same as $\int e^{-x}\mathrm dx$ and is possible to find using elementary functions.
I don't think the original integral has its antiderivative as an elementary function (though I didn't try to find it); but I started to wonder $-$ what if we were allowed to use any $f = f(x)$ as the function with respect to which we're integrating? Would it be possible to find the antiderivative? In this case $-$ sure, $f(x) = x^2$ will work since $\int \sinh^{-1}(x^2) \mathrm d(x^2)$ is just the same as $\int \sinh^{-1}(x) \mathrm dx$ and that's solvable with an elementary function.
So, my question is $-$ given the form $\int g\mathrm{df} $, where $f = f(x)$ and $g = g(x)$ are both elementary functions, is it always possible to find such $f$, so that $\int g\mathrm{df} $ is an elementary function?
